# Change date format in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

When running

```
 select processing_date from table;
```

i got this result **"04-30-2020 20.12.49.978711"**
what i want to change the format of the result to **"30-APR-20"**

is there a way i can do that ?

i tried `select to_date(processing_date,'mm-dd-yyyy') from table;` but it gives me errors

any help ?

Comment: What does documentation say about to_date function parameter's type? Date format and date value are different. Format can be set up in your IDE or in SQLPlus with `alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR'`. To select character string use [`to_char`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)

Comment: @astentx - as regards the 'RR' format ... Please. No.  Just. No.  That format element was meant as a _temporary_ fix to buy time in resolving the Y2k bug.  Nearly 21 years ago.  There is no reason not to use YYYY.

Answer (score 1):

You want `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(processing_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Dates are stored as an *internal* format, which you cannot change.  If you want the date formatted in a particular way, then one solution is to convert to a string with the format you want.

EDIT:

The date appears to be a string.  You can convert it to a date using:

```
select to_date(substr(processing_date, 1, 10), 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

You can then either use as-is or use `to_date()` to get the format you really want.

Comment: it gave me  ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: What is the data type of the column PROCESSING_DATE?  Please update your question to show the exact query that returned that error, along with the error - all together, in context.

Comment: it is varchar(29)

Comment: @TemoTemo For varchar you can convert it to date and then to char again `to_char(to_date(substr('04-30-2020 20.12.49.978711', 1, 10), 'mm-dd-yyyy'), 'dd-MON-yy')`. And cross your fingers no one will switch day's and month's places in future.